# Testing with PHP SimpleTest

Tags: php, unit-testing, simpletest

I'm running into an error while trying to run some simple tests with [SimpleTest for PHP](http://www.simpletest.org/en/start-testing.html).

Currently, I'm extending the class UnitTestCase as per the documentation. I'm trying to test different aspects of my class within a method. Here is my class:

```
<?php
class SimpleClass extends UnitTestCase {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->test();
    }

    private function test() {
        $x = true;
        $this->assertTrue($x, 'x is true');
    }
}
```

I've tried extending the TestSuite class and using the syntax in the documentation but I got the same error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getDumper() on a non-object in /simpletest/test_case.php on line 316
```

Any ideas on how I could do this or am I approaching class testing wrong?

Comment: If you can, you should really switch to PHPUnit. SimpleTest is a very nice framework for tests, but it does not get any more support, and the community able to help with issues is getting smaller and smaller. PHPUnit is the de facto standard framework for testing in PHP, with support almost everywhere.

Comment: That's great advice. I didn't look around much more after finding SimpleTest; now that I know everyone else uses PHPUnit I will switch to it. Thanks, should post as answer, no?

Comment: Avoiding the problem doesn't really count as an answer, does it?

Comment: true, just a newbie trying to learn :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a constructor in your test!

SimpleTest allows you to create classes with methods. If their name starts with "test", it is automatically recognized as a testing method that will get called if you start the test suite.

You created a constructor which calls your test method, and does an assertion without all the setup taking place, so SimpleTest does not have a reporter class that is needed to wrap it's test findings into a nice output.

Read the tutorial more closely, and you'll find some hints on how to set up a test suite or how to start a single test:

> Let us suppose we are testing a simple file logging class called Log in classes/log.php. We start by creating a test script which we will call tests/log_test.php and populate it as follows...

Code example adapted from the documentation:

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once('../classes/log.php');

class TestOfLogging extends UnitTestCase {
    function testLogCreatesNewFileOnFirstMessage() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
?>
```

Note there is no constructor, and the autorun file will take care to run the test if this file is executed with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I really like the scriptable browser that comes with SimpleTest and it's some nice lightweight testing too. I tried going through PHPUnit and the installation/documentation is lengthy.

Comment: SimpleTest is sort of simple, and the browser is nice. But the scripted browser has it's limitations - you would use Selenium to remotely control a real browser with Javascript support, and PHPUnit has an adapter to control Selenium. However the principles of testing are the same - you'd be able to switch to PHPUnit later.

Comment: @Sven I think the OP can use __constructor, just has to make sure he calls the parent constructor `parent::__construct()` (in theory it should work). Although it is not the prettiest solution, eventually to catch the arguments of the call `call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), get_func_args())`

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov While in theory you are right, why would you in practice do that? SimpleTest has a general default way to create test classes and test methods. Why deviate and explicitly call the test methods?

Comment: @Sven you are entirely right, I just wanted to mention that it is possible, it is not adviceable and tbh I don't see much point in what the OP did. I am unsure if simple test has equivalent to <code>protected function setup(); </code> that is the main reason I mentioned it.